# How do I test an AJAX based code locally on my PC?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, linux, windows

I am learning web development. Currently, I am learning AJAX. I am trying to run an example code, where the server side would return back text read from a file residing on the server. The example function is given below.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     myHeading.textContent = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "some_file_on_the_server.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Now, my question is, how can I check this code locally on my PC, and where would I need to place some_file_on_the_server.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an HTTP server of some kind to serve up that file, if you want to properly use AJAX.

These days, I prefer to use a [Vagrant box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/).  Vagrant is a tool for setting up development environments, usually on a local VM.  You add one file to your code, and then other developers can have the same development environment as you.  There are pre-configured boxes, and it's trivial to add a bit of extra provisioning script to set up a web server how you want it.

Comment: What about WAMP/LAMP server?

Comment: @pythonic Sure, you can do that but it's far easier just to fire up a Vagrant box.  Plus, I think you'll find Nginx to be much nicer to work with and generally faster than Apache.  The best reason to use a VM for a development server is to simulate your production environment as closely as reasonable.

Comment: I see. One more thing I need to ask you. On the free web hosting servers, is it possible to install your own softwares on those servers. For example I would want to install some python libraries using pip on the server. Moreover, which free web host server would you recommend?

Comment: @pythonic I wouldn't recommend any free web hosting.  If you go with someone like Digital Ocean, it's only $5 and you can do whatever you want.  Or, you can go the AWS route and it's free for a year but around ~$12/mo. after that.

Comment: @pythonic Just making sure you understand what I'm suggesting... I'm suggesting running a development VM on your computer, not hosting somewhere.

Comment: Of course I understood what you meant :). I was just taking your advise on free web services as well. Thanks for the information. I will check out Digital ocean. That one seems to be ideal.